# How to transition from a local Django development server to a restricted public test server?

Tags: web-server, web-hosting, django

I am working on a website that should not be open for public viewing. I'm currently developing on my local computer using manage.py and runserver.

However, I want to make the site publicly accessible to only a few certain people. These people are not developers, so they don't need access to the code. Also, since they aren't developers, it should be a somewhat user friendly solution. They just need access to view my current changes 24 hours a day.

I considered trying to do something with ALLOWED_HOSTS, but these people are on the go and login from many different IPs, some of which I'm sure are dynamic.

I considered setting the landing page as a login, but the website already has a complicated login system with multiple user types that these people will need to create multiple accounts to view and test different website features. Creating a separate login just for overall website access and then having the ability to still login to test other accounts seemed like way too much overhead and not user friendly. I figured there must be a better solution.

So, what is the best way to share a Django website to a limited non developer audience during development while ensuring that the random public doesn't have access? Is there a package or service that does this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just deploy it as you eventually will to production, e.g. nginx, gunicorn, etc., but to the private server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible idea is to give testers **client-side X509 certificates**.

- A person enters their certificate and private key into their browser. In my Firefox it's in Preferences -> Privacy -> scroll to the very bottom -> View Certificates -> tab Your Certificates -> Import
- Your end of SSL/TLS connection (nginx reverse proxy, haproxy, apache, etc) although listens on a public 443 port, is configured not only to serve the usual server-side certificate, but also to require a successful verification of a **client-side** certificate (you configure to only accept tester's certificates obviously).
- These are advanced SSL/TLS options on your end, so for example AWS ALB implementation of https is insufficient.
- Only https usage can be authorized this way, not plaintext http.
- This doesn't impact contents of http GET/POST/cookie at all, therefore it doesn't impact authentication schemes at these levels.
- Unauthorized browsers display an SSL/TLS error - they cannot pass any GET/POST whatsoever.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the response.

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining why it is worth the effort over simply sending them an HBA link like `https://user:pass@domain.example/app`.

Comment: @anx That's another good option, worth a separate answer.